# flip texture horizontally in Kernal function in metal

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

I just need to flip texture horizontally using kernel function in metal. Here is my kernel.

```
kernel void compute(
                    texture2d<float,access::read> des [[texture(0)]],
                    texture2d<float, access::write> src [[texture(1)]],
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{


    float4 flipColor = src.read(uint2(gid.x,1536 - gid.y));

    des.write(flipColor, gid);
}
```

here source texture is the texture which I need to flip. I am reading from source texture and writing to destination texture. But it is not working correctly. (giving a transparent texture)

What would be the reason? Suggestion, please?

Comment: You can make this more general by replacing the hardcoded height with `src.get_height()`. As for the unexpected result, is this on iOS or macOS? What storage mode is the destination texture in? How are you dispatching the work? How are you determining that the destination is transparent? Have you tried using GPU Frame Capture to examine what's going on?

Comment: I figured it out.I have passed same texture as source & destination. So what happened was while reading it try to write to same texture which caused unexpected result.Btw thanks @warrenm